# React test fails on wrapper.instance()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to React unit testing and I'm trying to write a test for a component method.

Taking the below example, I need to write a test for the `changeHandler` method of `ComponentA`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ComponentA extends Component {
    changeHandler = () => {
        // additional logic here
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Field
                    name='text'
                    onChange={ () => this.changeHandler() }
                    component={renderTextField}>
                </Field>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ComponentA.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=> ({

})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

})

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'componentForm',
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentA));
```

This is how I tried to achieve my goal:

```
import React from 'react';
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
import { createMount } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Component Form', () => {
  let mount, store, wrapper;

  const mockStore = configureMockStore({});
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore([]),
    mount = createMount({strict: false}),
    wrapper = shallow(<ComponentA store={store}/>).dive()
  });


  it('should change values', () => {
    wrapper.instance().changeHandler()
  });
});
```

But running the tests I'm getting

> TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).changeHandler is not a function`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... am I missing something?

Additional details:

using `shallow().dive().dive().dive().dive().dive().dive().dive()` the `changeHandler` method shows up, but I'm getting `undefined` when doing `console.log(wrapper.instance().changeHandler()`:

```
  ComponentA {
        props: 
         { array: 
            { insert: [Function],
              move: [Function],
              pop: [Function],
              push: [Function],
              remove: [Function],
              removeAll: [Function],
              shift: [Function],
              splice: [Function],
              swap: [Function],
              unshift: [Function] },
           anyTouched: false,
           asyncValidate: [Function],
           asyncValidating: false,
           blur: [Function],
           change: [Function],
           clearSubmit: [Function],
           destroy: [Function],
           dirty: false,
           dispatch: [Function: dispatch],
           error: undefined,
           form: 'campaign',
           handleSubmit: [Function],
           initialize: [Function],
           initialized: false,
           initialValues: undefined,
           invalid: false,
           pristine: true,
           reset: [Function],
           resetSection: [Function],
           submitting: false,
           submitFailed: false,
           submitSucceeded: false,
           touch: [Function],
           untouch: [Function],
           valid: true,
           warning: undefined,
           currentUser: { username: 'test', userId: 1 },
           codes: { bitlyCompany: [] },
           config: { classificationsPermissions: [Object] },
           codeConfiguration: { status: 'In Progress' },
           store: 
            { getState: [Function: getState],
              getActions: [Function: getActions],
              dispatch: [Function: dispatch],
              clearActions: [Function: clearActions],
              subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
              replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer] },
           pure: true,
           validate: [Function],
           triggerSubmit: undefined,
           autofill: [Function],
           clearFields: [Function],
           clearSubmitErrors: [Function],
           clearAsyncError: [Function],
           submit: [Function],
           storeSubscription: 
            Subscription {
              store: [Object],
              parentSub: [Object],
              onStateChange: [Function: bound onStateChange],
              unsubscribe: [Function: unsubscribe],
              listeners: [Object] },
           },
        context: { router: undefined },
        refs: {},
        updater: 
         Updater {
           _renderer: 
            ReactShallowRenderer {
              _context: [Object],
              _element: [Object],
              _instance: [Circular],
              _newState: null,
              _rendered: [Object],
              _rendering: false,
              _forcedUpdate: false,
              _updater: [Circular],
              _dispatcher: [Object],
              _workInProgressHook: null,
              _firstWorkInProgressHook: null,
              _isReRender: false,
              _didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdate: false,
              _renderPhaseUpdates: null,
              _numberOfReRenders: 0 },
           _callbacks: [] },
        changeHandler: [Function],
        setState: [Function], }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help if you could `console.log` the result of `wrapper.instance()` so we can see what is actually being returned.

My guess would be that your component is wrapped inside multiple HOCs, which is why you should dive until you get to the correct component which has the `changeHandler`.

Meaning it would look something like this:

```
wrapper = shallow(<ComponentA store={store}/>).dive().dive() // etc.
```

Alternatively you could simulate a change event on the field and use that to test your handler. It would look something like the following:

```
wrapper.find(Field).simulate('change')
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the console logs. Tried to find the field, but it returns no elements....

Comment: @Valip looks like you need another dive, could you try adding dives until you get the correct component in the output? If you want to go the `.find` route, you could try using `.mount` instead of `.shallow` so the entire tree is rendered.

Comment: Using below 7 dives it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeHandler' of null/unefined`, on 7 dives it just shows `undefined` for `wrapper.instance().changeHandler()`

Comment: It seems that the `changeHandler` shows up for 7 dives, but not sure why I'm getting undefined when trying to call it

Comment: Ok, it's `undefined` because it's not returning anything in the Component.

Comment: @Valip I was about to comment that, glad it finally worked, I'll update my answer to better reflect the final solution